# Partial-izing the template does not behave as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is an interface that takes in two templates. the returned function should be a partial of one of the templates (this is a take on the React-Redux):

```
export type IState<TState, TOwnProps> = {
    connect: (mapStateToProps: MapStateToProps<TState, Partial<TOwnProps>>) => () => any;
}
export type MapStateToProps<TState, TStateProps> = (state: TState) => TStateProps;
```

Now, here is the example of a state that would want to use this:

```
interface IAppState {
    services: string[]
}

interface IAppProps {
    services: string[];
    count: number;
}

const MyState: IState<IAppState, IAppProps>;
MyState.connect(
    (state) => {
        return {
            services: state.services,
            foo: null
        }
    }
);
```

`MyState.connect` should expect one function (which it does). The argument should be of type `IAppState` (which it is). But the return is suppose to be a `Partial<IAppProps>`. However, as you can see I am returning `foo: null` too and the service is not complaining about this.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the option `strictNullCheck` enabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you try this:

```
MyState.connect(
    (state) : Partial<IAppProps> => {
        return {
            services: state.services,
            foo: null
        }
    }
);
```

the compiler starts complaining. What happens here is the following:

The type of the inner lambda function is inferred as `() => {services:IAppState, foo:null}`. And the this can be passed as a parameter to connect as it is compatible with `() => Partial<IAppProps>` (It has all the required fields.) So the compiler does not compare the type of the object literal, but compares the type of the function.

Strictly speaking, even `const x : {foo:number} = {foo:1, bar:2};` would be typesafe, because the value has all the required properties. But usually a more strict check is desirable when writing object literals, that's why typescript has an additional rule: `Object literal may only specify known properties.`. This rule does not apply to functions return values though.

Comment: Two things. 1) I can actually set a completely different `interface` completely 
 `(state) : Partial<SomeOtherProps>` and the compiler does not complain. Why is that? I have clearly defined in the `IState` that my function connect should only accept `(state) : Partial<IAppProps>`. 

2) I wish not to set the return type again on the function. I just want to define the `State` interface once, and have all the types checked.